# ls -h reporting more diskusage then du -h, how?

Tags: linux, redhat

If I do a ls -h, I get a total of 126 Gb, whereas du -h is reporting half of it: 63 Gb.
It's a directory with 24 files. If I count all the individual filesizes I have a total of 126 Gb. There are no symbolic links.

What's causing the difference?

```
ls -alh
total 126G
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4.0K Dec 11 12:48 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4.0K May 19  2008 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    0 Dec 11 10:28 auto-opschoning.errtmp
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  11M Dec 11 12:33 auto-opschoning.logtmp
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K Feb 19  2016 backup
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 9.7M Dec 11 12:48 batchkop
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 9.7M Dec 11 12:48 batchkop.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 9.2G Dec 11 12:48 dispudet
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 9.2G Dec 11 12:48 dispudet.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 1.2G Dec 11 12:48 dispukop
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 1.2G Dec 11 12:48 dispukop.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 765M Dec 11 12:48 loktrail
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 765M Dec 11 12:48 loktrail.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root  19G Dec 11 12:48 orddet
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root  19G Dec 11 12:48 orddet.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 4.1G Dec 11 12:48 orddetkl
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 4.1G Dec 11 12:48 orddetkl.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 977M Dec 11 12:48 ordkop
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 977M Dec 11 12:48 ordkop.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root  12G Dec 11 12:48 trail
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root  12G Dec 11 12:48 trail.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 5.7G Dec 11 12:48 verzdud
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 7.4G Dec 11 12:48 verzdudd
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 7.4G Dec 11 12:48 verzdudd.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 5.7G Dec 11 12:48 verzdud.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 251M Dec 11 12:48 verzduk
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 251M Dec 11 12:48 verzduk.his
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 3.5G Dec 11 12:48 voorsnap
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 3.5G Dec 11 12:48 voorsnap.his

du -h
4.0K    ./backup
63G     .
```

Comment: See [What is the difference between du -h and ls -lh?](http://serverfault.com/q/290088/200076) in [sf].

Comment: could the .his files be hard links?

Comment: How do I find out if these are hard links?

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference here is related to the files that you are trying to get their space.

some files are called sparse files.

sparse files are files that their space is not fully physically allocated (they are virtually allocated not physically)

they are used a lot as virtual machine storage files and some data-structures need them .

you can use dd to create a sparse file and test with it

check this example i just did

```
h@localhost:~$ mkdir test
h@localhost:~$ cd test/
h@localhost:~/test$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file.img bs=1 count=0 seek=512M
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000214033 s, 0.0 kB/s
h@localhost:~/test$ ls -h
file.img
h@localhost:~/test$ ls -alh
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 h h 4.0K Dec 16 14:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 h h 4.0K Dec 16 14:02 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 h h 512M Dec 16 14:04 file.img
h@localhost:~/test$ du -c
4       .
4       total
h@localhost:~/test$
```

and as the link that was posted in comments says the diffrence between ls -h and du -c is that du -c will get the actual used space not the virtually allocated space while ls -h will give the virtual allocated space